# $S ( L )=\{x \ : \ x=x^{**}\} $ is the set of complemented elements of $L$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, lattice-orders

Let $L$ be a pseudocomplemented distributive lattice. Let $x^*$ denote the pseudocomplement of $x.$ Show that $S ( L )=\{x \ : \ x=x^{**}\} $  is the set of complemented
 elements of $L$.

It's easy enough to show that any complemented element of $L$ is in $S(L),$ it follows from the fact that if there is a complement it is the same as the pseudocomplement.

I'm having a very hard time showing the reciprocal, that is, any element in $S(L)$ is complemented. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, in a bounded distributive lattice, [the complement is unique](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Complement_in_Distributive_Lattice_is_Unique).
So, since $y^*$ is a complement of $y$ and of $y^{**}$, it follows that $y=y^{**}$.
Thus, $y^*=y^{***}$, yielding $x = x^{**}$, whenever $x=y^*$.

---

**EDIT**
With pseudo-complementation in place of complementation, that is, if $$x^* = \max \{ z \in L : x \wedge z = 0 \},$$
(this is what you mean, right?), then I'm not sure that is correct.
Check this example:

[image]

Here, $a^*=b^*=e, c^*=d, d^*=c$ and $e^*=a$.
It follows that $S(L) = \{ a,c,d,e \}$, but $c$ and $d$ are not complemented ($c \vee d \neq 1$).
Did I miss something in your definition?

Comment: I should have made it more clear, but $^*$ is denoting pseudocomplement.

Comment: @KingGhidorah It was clear enough; I looked at the title and didn't pay attention to that part of the text.

Comment: I think your counterexample is correct. Thank you.

What's strange is that I have seen this as an exercise in at least two books, and it's even on the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocomplement...

Thanks again.

Comment: @KingGhidorah Yes it seems to be precisely like that in that wikipedia article. Sometimes I'm a bit unsure on trusting what is written in wikipedia if I can't confirm it, but if you saw it in two books, that's really intriguing.

Comment: For instance it's ex 7.4 page 113 on T.S .Blyth's book Lattices and Ordered Algebraic Structures

Comment: @KingGhidorah The only way I can see to conciliate this is if we consider that those elements form a complemented lattice (with different join, $x \vee' y = (x \vee y)^{**}$), but would be an understatement because that actually forms a Boolean algebra (according to the wikipedia article and, I suppose, the books). Apart from that, I see no room for misinterpretation here...